# How to test a decorator which makes a decorated function being called forever in fixed time intervals

Tags: python, pytest, decorator

I have developed a decorator with which a decorated function is being called forever every x seconds.

```py
@run_periodically(cycle_time=1) # in seconds
def action(exec_time):
    print(f"exec_time: {exec_time}")
```

Calling the `action` function

results in the following output:

```
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:09.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:10.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:11.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:12.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:13.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:14.075368
exec_time: 2023-02-28 12:01:15.075368
...
```

Now I would like to write a test for my decorator, but I am not sure what the best approach would be.

I setup a test like this:

```py
def prepare_action(stop_time: datetime): 

    counter = 0

    @run_periodically(cycle_time=0.001)
    def action(exec_time: datetime):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        if exec_time > stop_time:
            assert counter == 3
            exit(42)

    return action
    


def test_run_periodically():
    stop_time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(milliseconds=3)
    action = prepare_action(stop_time=stop_time)
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        action(exec_time=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(milliseconds=1))
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.type == SystemExit
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.value.code == 42
```

The test works but I am not sure if I did a good job. I am worried that my way of setting up the test leaves room for flaky behaviour.

Do you know how an approach how to test a workflow which by design should not finish?

Comment: You can still interrupt the execution by raising (if you are not catching the broad `Exception` type in your decorator). You could e.g. write a dummy function that raises a custom error after a certain amount invocations, decorate it with `@run_periodically` and execute in the test, intercepting the custom error with `pytest.raises`. That said, there are lots of solutions for periodic execution of tasks in Python - from stdlib‘s `threading.Timer` to third-party libraries ranging from `backoff` to `celery`.

Comment: I mean, if you would e.g. use `threasing.Timer` in the decorator impl, you would just mock the timer behavior and verify the decorator handles the different scenarios correctly.